# Ruby google_drive gem oAuth2 saving

Tags: ruby, oauth, google-drive-api

So before the update there was a simple way to log into google drive and manipulate your google docs - with ruby.

Before you were able to log into your google drive with this.

```
require 'google_drive'
$session = GoogleDrive.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
```

But now you get the warning message:

```
WARNING: GoogleDrive.login is deprecated and will be removed in the next version. Use GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth instead.
```

So I went to the git [hub page](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) to see how google wants us to use their services with high level languages, and found out they want us to use oAuth2. Like so.

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google_drive'

client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'Example Ruby application',
  :application_version => '1.0.0'
)
auth = client.authorization
auth.client_id = "YOUR CLIENT ID"
auth.client_secret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET"
auth.scope =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " +
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
auth.redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
print("1. Open this page:\n%s\n\n" % auth.authorization_uri)
print("2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page: ")
auth.code = $stdin.gets.chomp
auth.fetch_access_token!
access_token = auth.access_token

$session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)
```

This is fine and all but I can't save the auth variable. 
I would like to hard code this in the script so I don't have to keep going to google to get a new access_token.

So I've tried to get the access_token and adding it to the script like so.

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google_drive'

client = Google::APIClient.new
access_token = "TokenFromGoogleHardCoded"

$session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)

# $session doesn't connect
```

I'm not sure I'm attacking this problem in the correct manor. I would like to save the complete auth variable and hard code it in my scripts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out this mess.

```
auth.scope =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " +
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
```

The auth.scope is missing a url. [REFERENCE](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/59) from github

```
auth.scope =
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" +
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " +
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
```

You can reuse your access_token, but first you need to get it. WARNING: The auth.access_token is only good for an hour. If you need another one you need to call auth.refresh! This will issue you another access_token.

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google_drive'

client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'Example Ruby application',
  :application_version => '1.0.0'
)
auth = client.authorization
auth.client_id = "YOUR CLIENT ID"
auth.client_secret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET"
auth.scope =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " +
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
auth.redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
print("1. Open this page:\n%s\n\n" % auth.authorization_uri)
print("2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page: ")
auth.code = $stdin.gets.chomp
auth.fetch_access_token!
access_token = auth.access_token

system'clear'
print "Save your access token\n\n"
print access_token  
print "\nSave your refresh token\n\n"
print auth.refresh_token
```

This chunk of code should print out your access_token/refresh_token in your console. Now you can hard code your application.

```
require "google/api_client"
require "google_driver"
client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'Example Ruby application',
  :application_version => '1.0.0'
)
auth = client.authorization
auth.client_id = "Your Client ID"
auth.client_secret = "Your client secret"

access_token = "token you saved from the terminal"

session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)

for file in session.files
   p file.title
end
```

And eventually your "access_token" will expire. At this point you need to "refresh" it. You can call to see if your access_token is expired by calling

```
auth.expires_at
```

You can get a new access token with this example.

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google_drive'


$client_id = "YOUR CLIENT ID"
$client_secret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET"
$refresh_token = "SAVED REFRESH TOKEN"

 client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'Example Ruby application', :application_version => '1.0.0')
    auth = client.authorization
    auth.client_id = $client_id
    auth.client_secret = $client_secret
    auth.scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " + "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
    auth.redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
    auth.refresh_token = $refresh_token

    #here's the magic sauce 
    auth.refresh! 

    #as you can see above auth.access_token wasn't passed a value
    # but if you call it now you'll see you have a new access_token

    auth.access_token
    => new token from server
```

Answer (score 4):

You might find it easier to use service accounts, as outlined here:

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/126#issuecomment-73542381

Answer (score 1):

Although Duck1337's answer will work, you don't actually need to call *auth.refresh!* with google_drive 1.0.*.

All you need to do is save the *refresh_token* from when you provided the authorization code in the first instance and then always pass that before calling *auth.fetch_access_token!* and the tokens will automatically get refreshed.

Below is what I use to login.  I use Environment variables rather that code constants, so I can add them to Heroku Config Vars and also to keep sensitive data out of the code.

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
    auth = client.authorization
    auth.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
    auth.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
    auth.scope = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
    ]
    auth.redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

    if ENV['GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN'] == "0" # Always start with 0 in your .env file, e.g. GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN = 0
      puts("1. Open this page:\n%s\n\n" % auth.authorization_uri)
      puts("2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page: ")
      auth.code = $stdin.gets.chomp
    end if

    auth.refresh_token = ENV['GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN'] #this will be 0 the first time around, but that's OK
    auth.fetch_access_token!

    if ENV['GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN'] == "0"   
      puts("3. Save this refresh token:\n%s\n\n" % auth.refresh_token) # you can now replace the 0 in your .env file with this token, so it'll be used permanently.  You can also add this to the Heroku Config Vars.
      ENV['GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN'] = auth.refresh_token #we'll set it here, so it works without having to alter the .env file for this call
    end if

    GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(auth.access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use capybara and navigate to the token page.  Grab it from the page source and save to a variable.  Plug the variable when needed.  The token string expires so I grab a new one each time I need to access the spreadsheet.