# Ruby 2.2.0 Google Drive OAuth refresh

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am trying to setup a command line backup app in ruby which accesses Google Drive using Oauth.  I have set everything up in the account, created my Client ID and Secret.  I seem to remember doing this before but cannot find the code.  I used this answer before I think: [Ruby google_drive gem oAuth2 saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789804/ruby-google-drive-gem-oauth2-saving)

I have made a class to handle the Google Drive stuff then there is the applications main file which if given "hard" as an argument will do the initial setup where you have to copy and paste the link into the web browser in order to get a code which you can then paste into the CLI to get the initial access token and refresh token.  This works and following these steps my list method (when not commented out) correctly lists everything in Google Drive.  When I do the initial setup I am manually copying the access and refresh tokens to .access_token and .refresh_token, these are loading in the code fine.

What is not working, is refreshing the token which I understand I need to do otherwise it will expire, meaning I will have to go through the initial setup again which is obviously a pain (and not suitable for a CRON job).  I am getting the following error when I run @auth.refresh!

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/signet-0.6.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:947:in `fetch_access_token': Authorization failed.  Server message: (Signet::AuthorizationError)
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/signet-0.6.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:964:in `fetch_access_token!'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/signet-0.6.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:981:in `refresh!'
    from /home/user/Development/BackupBadger/Sources/Mechanisms/GoogleDriveMechanism.rb:62:in `connect'
    from BackupBadger.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I have had a look to see what it might be but am for the moment stuck on why this error is triggering when I can seemingly authenticate (since I can list all files on the drive)

My main file

```
$root=File.join('/home/user/Development/BackupBadger')
$sources=File.join($root,'Sources')
require File.join($sources,'Mechanisms','GoogleDriveMechanism.rb')

badger = BackupBadger::GoogleDriveMechanism.new
if ARGV[0] == "hard" then
  badger.hard_setup
else
  badger.connect
  #badger.list
end
```

My class Google Drive

```
module BackupBadger

  require 'google/api_client'
  require 'google_drive'
  require 'pp'

  require File.join($sources,'Mechanism.rb')

  class GoogleDriveMechanism
    def initialize()
      @client = Google::APIClient.new(
        :application_name => 'Backup Badger',
        :application_version => '0.0.1'
      )
      @access_token_path = File.join($root,'.access_token')
      @refresh_token_path = File.join($root,'.refresh_token')
      @auth = nil
      @access_token = File.open(@access_token_path, "rb").read
      @refresh_token = File.open(@refresh_token_path, "rb").read
      @session = nil
      @client_id = 'CLIENT_ID'
      @client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
      @redirect_uri = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
      @scope =  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive " +
                "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
    end

    # Call this to do the initial setup, which requires pasting a url into a web broswer
    def hard_setup
      @auth = @client.authorization
      @auth.client_id = @client_id
      @auth.client_secret = @client_secret
      @auth.scope = @scope
      @auth.redirect_uri = @redirect_uri
      print("1. Open this page:\n%s\n\n" % @auth.authorization_uri)
      print("2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page: ")
      @auth.code = $stdin.gets.chomp
      @auth.fetch_access_token!
      @access_token = @auth.access_token

      system'clear'
      print "Save your access token\n\n"
      print @access_token  
      print "\nSave your refresh token\n\n"
      print @auth.refresh_token 
    end

    def connect
      @auth = @client.authorization
      @auth.client_id = @client_id
      @auth.client_secret = @client_secret
      @auth.scope = @scope
      @auth.redirect_uri = @redirect_uri
      @auth.refresh_token = @refresh_token

      puts @access_token
      puts @refresh_token

      # Error is here
      @auth.refresh!

      @refresh_token = @auth.refresh_token
      @access_token = @auth.access_token

      File.write(@refresh_token_path, @refresh_token) if @refresh_token
      File.write(@access_token_path, @access_token) if @access_token

      puts @access_token
      puts @refresh_token
    end

    def list
      @session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(@access_token)
      for file in @session.files
         p file.title
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tl;dr is simply "how do I use a refresh token to get a new access token", then the answer is https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

I won't paste the code coz it's likely to change, but in essence you simply POST to a Google URL and the JSON response is a shiny new access token.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this.  My question however was more specific to the google-drive Ruby gem.  It was my understanding that calling the refresh! method would get my new refresh token.  It is this which I am querying.  Yes I could do a POST myself but why do that when a Gem exists?

Comment: "why do that when a Gem exists?". The answer imho is because if you had done, you wouldn't have had to post this question to SO to second guess how the gem works, and then hope that Google doesn't change the library in future to do something different.